# Getting correct color of status bar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Okay I am having some trouble coloring my status bar. I have a pretty simple app that moves between two views. I tried coloring the status bars of the navigation controller with this code

```
  [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x067AB5)];
```

But it did not work until I removed the "navigation controller's" status bars and dragged status bars into the storyboard. Then I wanted the status bar to match the color so I deleted the navigation controller and it worked! I think the navigation controller status bar was not allowing the status bar to be colored correctly. However, without a navigation controller I cannot add a "push" segue. This is what it looks like with the navigation controller[image: This is what it]

And here it is without[image]

I don't know what the solution is because I need the nav controller for this to work I think. For some reason there is no "show" option. Let me know what I should do. Thank you!

Comment: have you found the solution yet? I experience the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per, http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/ (although we are now working with iOS 8, the color of the navigation bar and status bar are the same by default.  It sounds like you really do want their colors to be the same (is this what you mean by "correct color"?).

To do this in storyboard, I would add your first UIViewController to the storyboard.  Click this UIViewController, go up to the menu and click Editor -> Embed in -> Navigation Controller.  You will see now that the Navigation Controller is the initial scene and your UIViewController is the root view controller.  Then add a second UIViewController.  Ctrl drag from the first UIViewController to the second view controller and create a show (push) segue.

Now to change the color of the UINavigationController.  Click of the UINavigationController (the first scene).  In the outline on the left, click on the Navigation Bar.  In the inspector on the right, you should see a Navigation Bar section with Style and Tint underneath.  For a solid look, you can select Black Opaque and change the tint color to whatever you like.  Note that your selection will roll through to your UIViewControllers.  When you build the app, the status bar should now match the color of the navigation bar.

Comment: the problem is, when you don't use Push Seque, but a Modal one, the status bar doesn't infer the color of the navigation bar, but the color of the ViewController(I guess), which in my case is white. so I see something like this [link](http://s24.postimg.org/6gk7398p1/Screen_Shot_2015_05_17_at_20_10_36.png)