# get navigation bar color to give it to status bar color on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, navbar, statusbar, theos

i'm new here and i actually started learning recently and i'm making my first Theos tweak (i made some with flex) and as i said in the title i'm looking for a way to get nav bar color or a color from part of the screen and apply it as the status bar background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to write a function to detect your targetPixelColor as a UIColor, and then apply that color to the status bar within viewWillAppear using something like

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:targetPixelColor];
}
```

Comment: What should be the header? I entered UINavigationbarC ontroller but i got error

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean what should be the header?

Comment: i mean the %hook "header" on the top

Comment: this is my code(don't blame me if it looks funny! i dont know much coding): 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
%hook UINavigationController
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self.navigationController.navigationBar];
[setBarTintColor:targetPixelColor]
%orig
}

%end

Comment: also this is the error i get in terminal when i try to make it: Tweak.xm:4:41: error: expected identifier
[self.navigationController.navigationBar];
                                        ^
Tweak.xm:5:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'setBarTintColor'
[setBarTintColor:targetPixelColor]

Comment: so i changed the code to: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{ 
[self.navigationController.navigationBar -setBarTintColor:targetPixelColor];
}
and i just have one error: undeclared identifier setBarTintColor

Comment: Do you know the specific color of the status bar that you are trying to apply? If so, you can just do it using storyboard. Click of the UINavigationController (the first scene). In the outline on the left, click on the Navigation Bar. In the inspector on the right, you should see a Navigation Bar section with Style and Tint underneath.When you build the app, the status bar should now match the color of the navigation bar as you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27912671/3358766)

Comment: my idea was to make a tweak like statuscolor made by alan yip but in ios 7+ style but thx anyways helped me so much 

Comment: no problem. would you mind upvoting and starring my answer? that way I can engage more on the platform. would really appreciate it

Comment: sorry i thought i did it  u deserved it

Answer (score 0):

you should add just blow code in view didLoad. 
[Example is here]I added light Gary color.you could add your own choice colour.

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.lightGray